# "bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

Tags: windows, docker, networking, routes, port

Say we have `frontend` and `backend` containers based on Docker Desktop (for Windows).

`Backend` container uses port `9001`, and the `frontend` container listens to `9001`.

The problem is that port `9001` is already in use by Windows 10 by the Intel driver, and it is impossible to run a container on this port:

> Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9001: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

Could you please advise what is the way to handle this port if there is no ability to change it directly from application code?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ways:

- When either using a `docker run` command, specify the host port to use, and set it to something other than `9001`. i.e. `-p 9002:9001` or `Docker Compose`, i.e.

```
ports:
      - '9002:9001'
```

Then use port `9002` instead of `9001` when accessing the container from the host (Win 10).

- Use Nginx and set up a reverse proxy, leave the host port empty when starting the container so no external post is opened on the host, and have the reverse proxy pass it over to the container's `9001` port.

Answer (score 1):

From another thread, this was the solution on windows for a similar error message:

```
net stop winnat
docker start container_name
net start winnat
```

Comment: For me, "net stop winnat" and "net start winnat" also works for a while.